# Quickblox Android: Total unread messages count request

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I have seen that in the iOS sdk and the API I can get the total unread messages count, but I couldn't find a way to do the same with the Quickblox Android SDK.
Is there a way to achieve this?

I need something similar to this but for Android instead of iOS:

```
let dialogsIDs: NSSet = NSSet(array: ["55fae39ca28f9a701d0058fb"])
QBRequest.totalUnreadMessageCountForDialogsWithIDs(dialogsIDs as! Set<String>, successBlock: { (response: QBResponse, count: UInt, dialogs: [String : AnyObject]?) -> Void in

}) { (response: QBResponse) -> Void in

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/issues/167) with this in the quickblox github repo and they have already included it in the next release.
It is already available in the last snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch chat dialogs there is a key inside each dialog '**unreadMessageCount**' which is responsible for providing unread count.