# Android : Quickblox get total unread message count

Tags: android, message, quickblox, quickblox-android

I have referred these links

1. [Quickblox Android: Total unread messages count request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569272/quickblox-android-total-unread-messages-count-request)
2. http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-android#Unread_messages_count

But problem is it gives cannot resolve for this method getTotalUnreadMessagesCount()

Please help

Answer (score 1):

just use last version of quickblox android SDK chat and quickblox  core sdk (up to 2.5.2).
more information here "Framework changelog":
http://quickblox.com/developers/Android